# Joining multiple rows into comma separated strings by group in Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, concatenation

I have a dataframe similar to the one below:

| ID | Award | Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | PELL | FED | 2021-06-01 |
| 01 | SCH | LOC | 2021-06-01 |
| 02 | SCH | LOC | 2021-06-04 |
| 03 | GRANT | STA | 2021-06-02 |
| 03 | PELL | FED | 2021-06-15 |
| 03 | SCH | LOC | 2021-07-01 |

I want to convert this to the following dataframe:

| ID | Award | Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | PELL, SCH | FED, LOC | 2021-06-01, 2021-06-01 |
| 02 | SCH | LOC | 2021-06-04 |
| 03 | GRANT, PELL, SCH | STA, FED, LOC | 2021-06-02, 2021-06-15, 2021-07-01 |

In this case, I am grouping by ID. However, there may be more than one grouping column (for instance, ID and TERM instead of just ID). I have the grouping columns stored in a list variable named 'keys'.

Each grouping could have a different number of items, but the non-grouping columns all have the same number of items for each group (for ID=01 in the dataframes above, the other columns will all have 2 rows).

All the columns are read in as strings from a csv file (using dtype=str on pd.read_csv) to prevent changing any of the values from their original value (I don't want numbers reinterpreted or date formats changed).

I have tried something along the lines of the following, but none of these seem to work.

```
import pandas as pd 
keys = ['ID']
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID' : ['01','01','02','03','03','03'],
    'Award' : ['PELL','SCH','SCH','GRANT','PELL','SCH'],
    'Type' : ['FED','LOC','LOC','STA','FED','LOC'],
    'Date' : ['2021-06-01','2021-06-01','2021-06-04','2021-06-02','2021-06-15','2021-07-01'],
})
dfb = df.groupby(keys).apply(', '.join) # This results in the column names being joined together, not the column values
dfc = df.groupby(keys).agg(list) # This results in lists instead of concatenated strings
```

Output:

```
dfb
ID
01    ID, Award, Type, Date
02    ID, Award, Type, Date
03    ID, Award, Type, Date
dtype: object

dfc
                 Award             Type                                  Date
ID                                                                           
01         [PELL, SCH]       [FED, LOC]              [2021-06-01, 2021-06-01]
02               [SCH]            [LOC]                          [2021-06-04]
03  [GRANT, PELL, SCH]  [STA, FED, LOC]  [2021-06-02, 2021-06-15, 2021-07-01]
```

I would love a pointer as to where to go with this. I am still struggling with this aspect of Python, for sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

1. Create a dictionary that has all the required columns except `ID` as key and `lambda x: list(x)` as function.
2. Use `groupby` with `agg` to apply the independent functions on each column.
3. If you want to convert the `list` to a concatenated string, then just change the lambda function to `lambda x: ', '.join(list(x))`

More details on how to work with complex groupby and aggregates can be found on my [blog here](http://akshaysehgal.com/groupby.html), if you are interested.

```
g = {i:lambda x: ', '.join(list(x)) for i in df.columns[1:]}

output = df.groupby(['ID']).agg(g).reset_index()
print(output)
```

```
   ID             Award           Type                                Date
0  01         PELL, SCH       FED, LOC              2021-06-01, 2021-06-01
1  02               SCH            LOC                          2021-06-04
2  03  GRANT, PELL, SCH  STA, FED, LOC  2021-06-02, 2021-06-15, 2021-07-01
```

**EDIT:**

If the goal is to only get a string with comma separation, then a shorter way as suggested by @Henry Ecker is ..

```
output = df.groupby(['ID'], as_index=False).agg(', '.join)
```

.. using only the aggregate with the method itself.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you. I am digging into to you blog now to learn more about this but this works perfectly.

Comment: glad to help anytime. Feel free to share your feedback on the blog as it will help me improve it further.

Comment: Wouldn't `output = df.groupby(['ID'], as_index=False).agg(', '.join)` work the same here without the mapping dictionary or the `lambda` or have I missed a requirement? As an aside, binding a `lambda` to an identifier with an assignment operation is [against PEP8 guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id49)

Comment: that would definately work @HenryEcker. but i added the `list` initially and the `', '.join` after that separately since the requirement was a bit unclear.

Comment: Thanks, @HenryEcker. I thought I tried that variation, but apparently not. I have streamlined the code with your recommendations. BTW Akshay, the blog was very helpful. Great examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pivot_table` for exactly this:

```
df.pivot_table(index="ID", values=["Award", "Type", "Date"], aggfunc=lambda x: ", ".join(x))
```

result:

```
               Award                                Date           Type
ID
01         PELL, SCH              2021-06-01, 2021-06-01       FED, LOC
02               SCH                          2021-06-04            LOC
03  GRANT, PELL, SCH  2021-06-02, 2021-06-15, 2021-07-01  STA, FED, LOC
```

If the arguments are confusing (pivots can take some getting used to): `index` is the column you want the resulting table to be indexed by, `values` are the the columns you want to aggregate in some way keyed by `index` values, and `aggfunc` is a function to convert that collection/list to a single value.

Comment: That is nice and clean. Thanks for sharing. I have added this as a comment in my code for future reference, but it works exactly as advertised.